# Python/Pandas: drop columns *not* containing either of two strings in one step?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe ('df') containing several columns and would like to only keep those columns with a column header starting with the prefix 'x1' or 'x4'. That is, I want to 'drop' all columns except those with a column header starting with either 'x1' or 'x4'.

How can I do this in one step?

I know that if I wanted to keep only those columns with the `x1` prefix I could do:

`df = df [df.columns.drop(list(df .filter(regex='x1')))]`

..but this results in me losing columns with the `x4` prefix, which I want to keep.

Similarly, if I wanted to keep only those columns with the `x4` prefix I can do:

`df = df [df.columns.drop(list(df .filter(regex='x4')))]`

..but this results in me losing columns with the `x1` prefix, which I want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use df.loc with list comprehension:

```
df.loc[:, [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(('x1', 'x4'))]]
```

It will show you all rows and columns which have 'x1' or 'x4' at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you. Question, is there a way to specify the 'axis' in this command, e.g. `,axis=1` ?

Comment: The construction of loc is: df.loc[rows, columns]. If you use df.loc[:, :], it will show you all rows and all columns. In this case we choose all rows and specify the columns, so it checks everything what is in columns axis after comma and there wouldn't be a need to add anything more, even if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the desired columns first and then just select those columns.

```py
data = [{"x1":"a", "x2":"a", "x4":"a"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

desired_columns = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith("x1") or x.startswith("x4")]
df = df[desired_columns]
```

You can also use a function:

```py
def is_valid(x):
    return x.startswith("x1") or x.startswith("x4")

data = [{"x1":"a", "x2":"a", "x4":"a"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

desired_columns = [x for x in df.columns if is_valid(x)]
df = df[desired_columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter option,

```
df.filter(regex='^x1|^x4')
```